# Why is ngModel 'null' when switching 'multiple' attribute in select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm developing a snippet for a use case, but trying to keep it simply, I went for a basic `multiple` switching exercise.

The problem is that `ngModel` is null when select's multiple attribute is switched dynamically by a directive who switches the attribute by a binding:

**Expected behaviour**

```
                                  Expected            Got
    Select and option:            ngModel: [1]    ✓ | ngModel: 1 ✓
    multiple = false
    [option]
    [  1  •]
    [  2   ]
    [  3   ]
                                  Expected            Got
    Select and option:            ngModel: [1, 3] ✓ | ngModel: null ✕
    multiple = true
    [option]
    [  1  •]
    [  2   ]
    [  3  •]
```

The idea is simply, (again) I have a button witch switch a boolean variable so the multiple attribute is toggled in a select. I was based on these answers for making a directive since people suggest is a better approach, so why not?!

I referenced these posts:
- [Conditional multiple input file with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043732/conditional-multiple-attribute-in-input-type-file-with-angularjs)
- [Conditional multi-select directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573299/conditional-multi-select-directive-in-angular)
- [Conditionally add the multiple attribute to UI Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872232/conditionally-add-the-multiple-attribute-to-ui-select)

The main problem is that my `ngModel` works well when the select is not  `multiple`, but when it's switched, and I select more than one element, it becames `null`.

It's there a approach you have fanced about this silly simple issue or should I go for the `ngIf` approach and keep stay in peace with my sanity?

**app.js: *Controller***

```
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.options  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.multiple = false;

    $scope.print = function() {
        console.log({ seleccion: $scope.selected, multiple: $scope.multiple});
    };

    $scope.toggleMultiple = function() {
        $scope.multiple = !$scope.multiple;
    }

    $scope.onChange = function(item) {
        console.log(item)
        $scope.print();
    }
});
```

**app.js: *Directive***

```
module.directive('ngMultiple', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngMultiple: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var unwatch = scope.$watch('ngMultiple', function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    element.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
                } else {
                    element.removeAttr('multiple');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{message}} <br />
    <select name="blabla" 

    ng-model="selected" id="blabla" 
    ng-multiple="multiple" 
    ng-options="o as o for o in options"
    ng-change="onChange(selected)">
    </select>
    <p>{{selectModel.selection}}</p>

    <p><button ng-click="print()">Print()</button></p>
    <p><button ng-click="toggleMultiple()">Toggle Multiple</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder if a track by in the ng-options might help in this case... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by- worth giving it a shot probably, if it doesn't work probably just go the ngIf or ngShow/Hide way of doing it (whatever works and looks less bad)

Comment: Hi Mister @shaunhusain. Finally I opted for the simple ngIf way. But I'll take a look for the link you provided. Thanks!